# Using Audacity to find and eliminate spikes

Tags: audio, repair, audacity

I downloaded a song that, for whatever reason, has tiny (much too short to eliminate using noise removal) peaks laced throughout it. The track is a little over an hour long, so finding and repairing each one would be ridiculous. Is there a way to find and select them all at once with Audacity, so that I could repair them all at once? If Audacity can't, is there an application that can?

This is what it looks like in Audacity.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAWrD.png]

Answer (score 0):

Compressor in Audacity audio editor (*Effect* -> *Compressor*) seems to do the job. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ3lOTDsN6c). Have you tried it?